# Are idioms affected by tone changing rules?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, tones, sandhi

For example, if I have the idiom:

一路平安

Does the tone of the 一 change to a second tone because 路 is fourth tone?

Comment: Simply put, yes. Tone changing rules are universal applied. I can't think of any situation where tone changing rules are ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it should be pronounced as the 2nd tone because it's put before character with the 4th tone. The sandhi rule applies with idioms too.

The cases `一` should be pronounced as the 1st tone, i.e. shouldn't change the tone, are listed as the follows:

> 1. 单独念时。如：一，一、二、三
> 2. 用在一词或一句的末尾。如：统一祖国，唯一条件，单一成分，表里如一，不论三七二十一
> 3. 表示年、月、日。如：1911年1月1日，一二•九运动，九•一八事变
> 4. 表示序数。如：第一村，第一名，第一等，第一位

(1. when used alone; 2. when used at the end of the word or sentence; 3. when used in date; 4. when used as ordinal number with the meaning "first".)

> “一”在上述语境中，不管它后面跟的字是什么声调，“一”的读音都保持其原调阴平，不发生变调。特别要引起注意的是第四种语境，因为许多序数在表述时采用了省略“第”的格式，这时“一”字也应读原调。

(Under the above circumstances, no matter what the following character's tone is, `一` should keep its original tone (i.e. the 1st tone) and doesn't change.)

[试析“一”声调的读法](http://www.gzu521.com/campus/article/qualification/200609/106883.htm)

Comment: @Belphegor It'll change to the 4th tone because 张 is pronounced as the 1st tone. Is the 4th case listed making you confusing about that? It's used as the numeral in `一张`, that's different with the 4th case listed.

Comment: I’m a bit confused about 2nd case where it says at end of the word. Not sure what would qualify as being at the end of the word. The example I gave with 张 I thought it was at the end of the word? Just now sure how to identify.

Comment: I’m mainly confused about 唯一条件，单一成分, so those don’t change because it’s end of sentence or something ? How do you identify the “end”?@songyuanyao

Comment: @Belphegor 唯一条件 could be seperated as 唯一 + 条件, i.e. 唯一 (and 单一) is an independent word and 一 is at the end of it. 一张 is different, 一 is used as the numeral, with the measure word 张 forms the word 一张, and then 一 is not at the end of the word.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you!